# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, web-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLuIr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49y0E.png)

Hello, I'm trying to code a simple web scraper with python but VSCode keeps giving me this error (as you can see in the images): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'. It's weird because with the auto-compiler of VSCode find_all is the first attribute that it suggests after the dot. I don't know if there's a syntax error or if it's something else. Someone has any idea on how to fix this? Thanks.

I tried fixing the code by myself but every version still gives me errors so I don't know what to try anymore. Another question here on Stackoverflow has the same problem but with images. The suggestion was an if-else cycle but... how? (It's my fault if I don't know it bc I'm kinda new to coding so please be patient I'm trying my best)

Comment: [Please don’t post code or error messages as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Not really: I understand that there's a problem with my code bc I get None instead of something else, but all I got from the answers of that question is to put an if-else cycle to test if it is in fact None or not (and it is). Am I missing something?

Comment: Try printing `response.text` to make sure it's what you are expecting. Often times, what is retrieved by `requests` is not the same as the DOM you see in your browser after JS processing.